# Response.redirect for MS Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, mschart

I have a chart control.

Now the functionality i want is if the user clicks on the chart it takes it to a new page along with it i need to send a value to that page.

i tried this but the click even is not working..

```
   protected void Chart1_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (Label1.Text != "1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Page2Chart.aspx?node=" + Label1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Page2Chart.aspx");
        }

    }
```

I know we can put a URL in the Html but then i cannot put a condition in it....?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart4" Height="202px" Width="360px" runat="server" 
                            onclick="Chart4_Click" >
                            <Series>

                                <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" Name="Series1" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt" >
                                </asp:Series>
                            </Series>
                            <ChartAreas>
                                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                                </asp:ChartArea>
                            </ChartAreas>
                            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Enabled="true" TableStyle="Tall" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold">
                </asp:Legend>
            </Legends>
        </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what your have written, per se.  When you say "the click even [sic] is not working", do you mean the event is not firing?  Or the Response.Redirects are not working as you planned?  Try debugging your app and set a breakpoint on the click handler to see if the event procedure is executing, and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the design view of the chart .

```
chart4.Series["seriesname"].Url = "somechartorpage.aspx?"+label1.text;              
chart4.Series["seriesname"].Points["name"].Url= "Detailedchart.aspx";
```

Comment: The edited code will fire only when we click on the series/point inside the chartarea,not anywhere on the chart.

Comment: hi thanks for the code.. there is a problem in the second line.. it says the name has to be an int.. also i din quiet understand why are we uing it..?? appreciate it..

Comment: I guess u dun need to use the second one , i just gave an example if you are using points then you can use it to pass it to another page to perform some logic, ny way if you find it useful mark it as answer cheers